# how to disable series low opacity state on hover over legends in highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

In my area chart, when I hover over legends, I can see some (low opacity) effects on that respective series plotting area? How to disable that low opacity series state on hover over legends?

```
   chart: {
    height: 450,
    type: 'area'
  },
  title: {
    text: ''
  },
```

tooltip: {
        shared: false,
        split: false,
        xDateFormat: '%b %d, %Y %H:%M',
        valueDecimals: 1
      },
      exporting: {
        enabled: false
      },
      navigator: {
        enabled: false,
      },
      xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
      },

Comment: Can you add in your code?

Answer (score 1):

You probably use `styled mode`, because this feature does not occur with standard options: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/z7j6rsa3/

To disable the hover effect, just overwrite `opacity` CSS style:

```
.highcharts-legend-series-active g.highcharts-series:not(.highcharts-series-hover),
.highcharts-legend-point-active .highcharts-point:not(.highcharts-point-hover),
.highcharts-legend-series-active .highcharts-markers:not(.highcharts-series-hover),
.highcharts-legend-series-active .highcharts-data-labels:not(.highcharts-series-hover) {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ozxq05fn/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this - change opacity for "1".

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        states: {
            inactive: {
                opacity: 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Example CodePen](https://codepen.io/magistr4815/pen/MWpRNLd)