# How to disable series low opacity state on concrete legend item hover?

Tags: highcharts

My problem is that I can't disable low opacity state only on "Total" legend item hover. I this case I use "Total" only to display sum of all series and it has no data for display. Also I have callback  on "Total" click.

[image]

Next example works fine for me, but not in Safari. "Total" is not hoverable and not clickable in Safari.

```
const series = [
  {
    name: 'Create',
    data: [3, 6, 2, 8, 18],
  },
  {
    name: 'Update',
    data: [6, 8, 9, 3, 10],
  },
  {
    name: 'Delete',
    data: [14, 8, 9, 17, 7],
  },
  {
    name: 'Total',
    visible: false, <----
  },
];
```

So I tried to change `visible to true`, and it works fine in all browsers, but now I have redundant "Total" hover effect as on screenshot.

"highcharts": "9.3.1"

Comment: I tried to recreate your example, but in my case, everything works fine. If you are using the styledMode, you can try the following solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53759153/how-to-disable-series-low-opacity-state-on-hover-over-legends-in-highcharts. Otherwise, recreate the problem in the online editor so I can work on it. Regards!

Comment: I found the solution when I tried to recreate it in the online editor.
My mistake was `color: none` as I want to make point near the "Total" to be transparent. And this rule broke hover behaviour on Safari. 


`legend: {
  itemHiddenStyle: {
    color: 'none',
  },
}`